# Android Studio doesn't start, fails saying components not installed & check for update continu

Tags: android

[image]

I installed Android SDK but after installation it continuosly checking updates & giving message The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, extra-android-m2repository, extra-google-m2repository